# Git Errors with interactive rebase. Unable to move the cache: Access is denied

Tags: windows, git, rebase

I'm using Git on windows on version 2.38.1
I'm currently having some errors when I'm trying to do an interactive rebase. Fortunately the operation still works at least. Here are the errors :

[image]

I tried the following:

1. Delete the cache folder. This only brought more issue where I was not able to clone repos
2. reinstalled git for windows. This solved some of the issue but I still have the errors that are in the screenshot
3. I found a couple of forum/blog that gave me things to try bu as of now it always led me to another dead end.

Would anyone have a clue on how I could get rid of those errors?
Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: These errors are not coming from Git: the log messages indicate that they're from some C++ source code, and Git has no C++ code in it, it's all plain C. Do you have a hook you run here and/or some editor magic? (This appears to be part of the Google Chrome source.)

Comment: I'm mainly using Gitlens on visual studio code to run Glyph. This gives me some idea on what to try next. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try first to make the `git rebase -i` from a simple CMD session, not from an editor (like VSCode) to see if the issue persists.

Do that in a local cloned repository in `C:\users\macaron\myRepository` (replace myRepository with your actual repository name).

If it works outside an IDE, but not inside, then, as [seen here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2157), it is probably due to a concurrent process which keeps an handle on those resources (`Cache` folders), preventing the `git` command to proceed.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work outside an IDE either

Comment: Do you have the exact same error message when done in a new cloned repository, outside an ide?

Comment: Yes I do have the exact same error

Comment: @Marc-AntoineCaron Does the error persists after a full reboot, and with a new CMD (without any other software launched)?

Comment: Yes it does. Also with a full reinstall of git